# How can I loop AudioBufferSourceNode with overlapping (using the same AudioBuffer)

Tags: web-audio-api

I need to loop my source with some cross parametr (in sec). It will be great to listen looping without interrupting on the sample border.AudioBufferSourceNode is  audioNode in my code. 
I faced with the problem of inability to reuse the buffer, is it possible to get around this?

```
    playNoteOn: function(indexNote){
        var attack = this.get('attack'),
            release = this.get('release'),
            volume = 1 + this.get('volume') / 100,
            reverb = _.clone(this.get('reverb')),
            loop = this.get('loop'), cross;

        //peace for Loop process
        if (loop) {
            //milli sec
            attack = this.get('startLoop')*1000;
            release = this.get('endLoop')*1000;
            //sec
            cross = this.get('crossLoop');
        }

        //peace for ADSR process
        var t0 = this.get('audioNode').context.currentTime,
            spread = attack/1000 + release/1000,
            attackSpread = t0 + attack/1000;

        [this.get('schema').leftGain, this.get('schema').rightGain].forEach(function(gain, index){
            gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(0);
            gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, t0);
            gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(volume, attackSpread);
            // gain.gain.setValueAtTime(volume, decaySpread);
            // gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, releaseSpread);
        });
        this.get('audioNode').connect(this.get('schema').splitter, 0, 0);
        this.get('audioNode').connect(this.get('schema').leftGain);
        this.get('audioNode').connect(this.get('schema').rightGain);
        this.get('audioNode').connect(this.get('schema').reverb);
        this.get('audioNode').connect(APP.Models.Synth.get('schema').reverb);

        APP.Models.Synth.get('effects').where({active: false}).forEach(function(effect){
            effect.get('node').disconnect();
        });

        APP.Models.Synth.get('effects').where({active: true}).forEach(function(effect){
            effect.get('node').disconnect();
            effect.get('node').setParams(effect.toJSON()).getNode(this.get('audioNode'), [this.get('schema').leftGain, this.get('schema').rightGain]);
        }, this);

        if(loop){
            this.get('audioNode').loop = true;
            this.get('audioNode').loopEnd = this.get('audioNode').buffer.duration - cross;
        }
        this.get('audioNode').start(t0);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse a buffer. Once stopped the sourcebuffer is gone forever. Where is your audio node object anyway? But that's no problem. When you decoded from a sound file you can  use the buffer from the decoding again. Just create more buffer sources. You can create as much as you like. What language are you using anyway? Say Some backgrounds to what you are doing and which frameworks you use.

Beware the difference between buffer from decoding and buffer source. Your audionode is a buffer source which can be feeded by a buffer. You can reuse the buffer but not the buffer source. So create the buffer source in your playnote code.